# Multiple taxonomies on same permalink rule

Tags: permalinks

I have a few taxonomies and it would be nice to be able to sort by two at time with a permalink. For example, I have two taxonomies, design-show-year and designer-or-firm. I'd like to have this permalink to get a listing of all these that match:

/design-show-year/2011/designer-or-firm/pete-klein/

Is this possible using the WordPress system by doing a rewrite and piping that into index.php, or can WordPress only handle one taxonomy at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting. I'm also looking for something similar. Using a facetted search/filter to use on multiple taxonomies.  Right now I am using Custom fields and Scribus 'old' Custom Field Taxonomies plugin to get similar functionality. I still wonder if taxonomies is the way to go when I am also looking for a way to search ranges (price between 5-10$).

Please update how it's going!

Answer (score 0):

I know it might not be the answer you're looking for, but I have to be honest;  I think you're gonna open a whole can of worms if you pursue that kind of permalink.

- It's not exactly semantic (admittedly objective)
- Many would consider it 'too nested'
- It's not clear (for users and for WordPress) if a parameter is;

  - a taxonomy term
  - a child of a taxonomy term
  - a secondary taxonomy

Plus I'd also add, since this is an archive-type request (that lists multiple posts), URL query parameters might be the better alternative (semantically and logistically).

In fact, I think something like scribu's [Taxonomy Drill-Down](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) would be awesome for this!

Comment: Thanks for the response TheDeadMedic. The taxonomy drill-down isn't what I'm looking for because each year needs a completely different layout. This layout will be created by non-technical people, so it needs to be in a separate page template file for each year, but we still want a cross-year search of other taxonomies.

Also Hierarchical post types are our of the question because they would need to select a parent. At 70+ new entries per year, a dropdown would be unusable quickly.

I have good reason for doing this. I just need to know if WordPress can handle 2 taxonmies, and if so, how.

Comment: I'm going to try piping in a $wp_query->query_var, then grabbing that in a permalink structure. WordPress 3.1 adds the ability to query multiple taxonomies as demonstrated here: http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/. I'll give this a try later and post the results.

Comment: Wish you all the best! Let us know how you get on